# gsub() on multiple dataframes in loop/lapply

Tags: r, gsub

I have two dataframes with a column named 'Title' in each, containing string. I need to reduce these strings in order to merge them. Now I want to make this as clean as possible in a loop such that I only have to write the gsub-function once.

Let's say I have:

```
df_1 <-read.table(text="
id Title
1 some_average_title
2 another:_one
3 the_third!
4 and_'the'_last
",header=TRUE,sep="")
```

and:

```
df_2 <-read.table(text="
id Title
1 some_average.title
2 another:one
3 the_third
4 and_the_last
",header=TRUE,sep="")
```

I would now run:

```
df_1$Title <- gsub(" |\\.|'|:|!|\\'|_", "", df_1$Title )
df_2$Title <- gsub(" |\\.|'|:|!|\\'|_", "", df_2$Title )
```

I tried the following loop:

```
for (dtfrm in c("dt_1", "df_2")) {
  assign(paste0(dtfrm, "$Title"),
    gsub(" |\\.|'|:|!|\\'|", "", get(paste0(dtfrm, "$Title")))
    )
  }
```

but it doesn't work - despite the lack of error messages.

I was also thinking about `lapply(list(dt_1, dt_2), function(w){ w$Title <- XXX })`but I don't know what to put for XXX because `gsub()`needs as a third argument the list of strings.

Comment: `lapply(list(df_1, df_2), function(w) gsub(" |\\.|'|:|!|\\'|_", "", w$Title))`? Or more general `lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "df_\\d")), function(w) gsub(" |\\.|'|:|!|\\'|_", "", w$Title))`

Comment: The regular expression `[ .':!_]` is a bit easier to read.

Comment: That `assign(paste0(dtfrm, "$Title")` won't work because you are hoping that `assign` will interpret the character result as a language object, and it's not set up to do that.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: Good suggestion, won't work in my (real) case where I also replace `\\'|“|”|\"`.

Comment: If you have some strings that are more than one character and others that are more than one character you can still do this: `[ab]|cd` which will match `a`, `b` or `cd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
for(df in c("df_1", "df_2")){
  assign(df, transform(get(df), Title =  gsub(" |\\.|'|:|!|\\'|_", "", Title)))
}
```

Testing:

```
df_1
  id            Title
1  1 someaveragetitle
2  2       anotherone
3  3         thethird
4  4       andthelast
```

And:

```
  df_2
  id            Title
1  1 someaveragetitle
2  2       anotherone
3  3         thethird
4  4       andthelast
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere between @David's comment and @Carlos's answer, with a little bit extra:

Use `mget` to grab your `data.frame`s, and `list2env` to copy over the original `data.frame`s if so desired.

`mget` + `lapply` will do the transformation....

```
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "df_\\d")), function(w)
  transform(w, Title = gsub(" |\\.|'|:|!|\\'|_", "", Title)))
# $df_1
#   id            Title
# 1  1 someaveragetitle
# 2  2       anotherone
# 3  3         thethird
# 4  4       andthelast
# 
# $df_2
#   id            Title
# 1  1 someaveragetitle
# 2  2       anotherone
# 3  3         thethird
# 4  4       andthelast
```

... but the result stays in a `list` and doesn't affect the original `data.frame`s:

```
# df_1
#   id              Title
# 1  1 some_average_title
# 2  2       another:_one
# 3  3         the_third!
# 4  4     and_'the'_last
```

If you did want to overwrite the `data.frame`s, try:

```
list2env(
  lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "df_\\d")), function(w) 
    transform(w, Title = gsub(" |\\.|'|:|!|\\'|_", "", Title))), 
  envir = .GlobalEnv)
df_1
#   id            Title
# 1  1 someaveragetitle
# 2  2       anotherone
# 3  3         thethird
# 4  4       andthelast
```

Comment: +1 for clean and fast code. Note: If someone has a name pattern that doesn't allow `ls()`, use `mget(c("df_1", "2ndftrm"))`.

Answer (score 0):

`get()` will allow you to grab your multiple datasets programatically.
`data.table()` will be helpful in modifying the columns in each with ease

```
## CREATING A FEW MORE DATA SETS
df_3 <- df_2
df_4 <- df_1
set.seed(1)
df_3$id <- sample(20, 4)
df_4$id <- sample(20, 4)

library(data.table)

dt_1 <- as.data.table(df_1)
dt_2 <- as.data.table(df_2)
dt_3 <- as.data.table(df_3)
dt_4 <- as.data.table(df_4)

## OR programatically: 

Numb_of_DTs <- 4

names_of_dt_objects <- paste("dt", 1:Numb_of_DTs, sep="_")  # dt_1, dt_2, etc
names_of_df_objects <- paste("df", 1:Numb_of_DTs, sep="_")  # dt_1, dt_2, etc

for (i in 1:Numb_of_DTs)
  assign(names_of_dt_objects[[i]], as.data.table(get(namse(names_of_df_objects[[i]]))))


for (dt.nm in names_of_dt_objects) {
  get(dt.nm)[, Title := gsub("[ .':!_]", "", Title)]
  ## set the key for merging in the next step
  setkey(get(dt.nm), Title)
  ## You might want to insert a line to clean up the column names, using 
  ##   setnames(get(dt.nm), OLD_NAMES, NEW_NAMES)
}


Reduce(merge, lapply(names_of_dt_objects, function(x) get(x)))
```